# Allowing edit approvals via the mobile app

Tags: feature-request, mobile-app

Has allowing edit approvals on the mobile app been considered? I rarely use SE on my computer when I have free time (I'm usually working on something), so I rarely ever go through the edit approval queue. I wouldn't be surprised if that's not uncommon.

If I could do approvals on the app though, I could do a few while waiting for the bus, or while in the bathroom (might as well multitask).

I know I can go in through the website, but it's not very mobile/skinny screen friendly (and this is on a Note 4).

Comment: @James That would be good. I only suggested edits because that's all I currently have access to. I'm not sure what all approval queues there are.

Comment: If you agree, you can click the blue button in your question and close it as dupe. And if you feel the need, add an answer (or comments) to the duped post adding any further info (although an upvote and possibly bounty are likely better options)

Comment: @James That box isn't showing up on the app (another suggestion). I'll close it when I get on my computer.

Comment: Hmm, that would be worth having as we like users to close as dupes when they can as it saves X users in the review queue etc. Might have already been asked tho ;)